# BDOO error con Persistence EclipseLink-4002

Tags: java

Estoy probando a incrementar y me da ahora este error:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «:»
  Position: 44
Error Code: 0
Call: UPDATE Article e SET e.preu = e.preu * (1+ :percentage/100)
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="UPDATE Article e SET e.preu = e.preu * (1+ :percentage/100)")
javax.persistence.PersistenceException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:308)
    at gestors.GestorArticleExtern.incrementarPreu(GestorArticleExtern.java:81)
    at TestGestors.provaIncrementarPreuDistribuidor1(TestGestors.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.processExceptionForCommError(DatabaseAccessor.java:1611)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:898)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:962)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:631)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2002)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataModifyQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1751)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:298)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2310)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2023)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:217)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:421)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:166)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:890)
```

el código es el siguiente:

```
   public void incrementarPreu(int codiDistribuidor, float percentantge) {
        //TODO completar el metode


  Query ap = em.createNamedQuery("Article.tots");
    List<Article>totsArticles= ap.getResultList();
    List<ArticleExtern> ae = new ArrayList();

    for(Article art : totsArticles){
        if(art instanceof ArticleExtern){

            ArticleExtern e = (ArticleExtern) art;

            if(e.getDistribuidor().getCodi() == codiDistribuidor){

                Query q;
                q= em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE Article e SET e.preu = e.preu * (1+ percentage/100)");
                q.setParameter("percentage", percentantge);
                em.getTransaction().begin();
                q.executeUpdate();
                em.getTransaction().commit();
            }
        }
```

Podéis ayudarme? Ya no se que mas hacer :(

Comment: Simplemente cambia el query eliminando ":"  de esta forma: q= em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE Article e SET e.preu = e.preu * (1+ percentage/100)");

Comment: ahora es otro error

Comment: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: no existe la columna «percentange»
  Position: 44
Error Code: 0
Call: UPDATE Article e SET e.preu = e.preu * (1+ percentange/100)
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="UPDATE Article e SET e.preu = e.preu * (1+ percentange/100)")

Comment: primeramente cambia percentantge por percentage para que no te confundas, lo que deseas es concatenar el valor de una variable.

Comment: lo he hecho y tampoco.. he modificado la pregunta para que veas el código como lo tengo ahora..

Comment: Como deseas obtener el valor de percentage para el query?

Comment: estoy super perdida Jorgesys! xD

Comment: Puede ser que me falte crear un query?

Comment: El query ya lo tienes pero debes concatenar el valor de la variable percentage , aunque en realidad se llama percentantge

Comment: @MontseMkd Lo que te dijo Jorge es que las variables no se llaman igual percentantge y esta varible  percentage se deben de llamar igual para que te funcione

Comment: pero ya he hecho las modificaciones y sigo sin conseguirlo.. :S :(

Comment: verifica que tu base de datos este activa ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza `createQuery` en lugar de `createNativeQuery`:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("UPDATE Article e SET e.preu = e.preu * (1 + :percentage/100)");
q.setParameter("percentage", percentantge);
```

Una consulta nativa ya no es JPQL sino SQL

Comment: no me da error pero me sale un failed en este : junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
 at TestGestors.provaIncrementarPreuDistribuidor1(TestGestors.java:189)

Comment: Independientemente de tus tests unitarios, se realizan los cambios a tu bd? Si es asi el problema es de como se realizan los tests